# I have a problem in my code i can't print the output result

Tags: c

Two lines containing a character on each.

Input Sample

```
C
U
```

Output Format

Multiple lines containing a character on each.

Output Sample

```
C
U
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

int main(void) {
    char string[3][SIZE];
    int i, j;
    int c;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      for(j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
        string[i][j] = 0;
      }
    printf("Enter three lines of text:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        j = 0;
        while ((j < SIZE) && ((c = getchar()) != '\n')) {
            string[i][j] = c;
            j++;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            printf("%c", string[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK first thing, do not post code in a comment.  Who can read that?  Edit your question, paste the code in the question and format as a [code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Also take the [tour] and read [ask]

Comment: Done sir sorry for that mistake

Answer (score 0):

When printing, you should break the for-loop when string[i][j] is zero (No character at that position).

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
        if (string[i][j] == 0)
            break;
        printf("%c", string[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```